# create a parent test class in Pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I am new to Pytest and having a little bit of trouble understanding the concept of parent test file if any such thing exists. Project structure looks like this:

```
Project
|
|----API
|    |----api_one.py
|    |----api_two.py
|
|----tests
|    |----test_a.py
|    |----test_b.py
tox.ini
```

What i want to do is: get the machine address and token from a config file and create my url in a BaseTest file and I want all of my test files to inherit that BaseTest file, so that i don't have to setup environment specific things again and again. Now I am able to create a `base_test.py` NOT in the tests folder but outside and import it but it really is an external file and moreover I would want to create `setUpClass` and `tearDownClass` in the base_test also for any future setups.

The files in the api folder are going to have classes for all the unique API calls that happens in my project, say stores, orders etc.

Now I may be wrong in several places and concepts here , but I am looking for solutions to having **a parent test file in pytest**

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to use pytest like how unittests is used. When it comes to pytest; setup and teardown code normally sits in a yield fixture, which in turn normally sits in a conftest.py file. https://pytest.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fixture.html#fixture-finalization-executing-teardown-code

Comment: yes i am actually trying to do that , i started using pytest because initial research showed it to be easier to implement, but this feature of using parent class is holding me back a bit now

Answer (score 0):

you can extend your test class with class defined base_test.py by defining setup class-method. code within setup function will be called automatically

e.g.

```
# base_test.py
class MyBaseTest
    def setup(self):
        # my setup stuff
        self._url = "http://blabla.com"
    def teardown(self):
        # my teardown stuff
```

where your test class should look like below

```
# test_a.py
class TestMyAPI(MyBaseTest):
    # my test stuff
```